# SSL ENABLE USING TELIT MODULE

Tags: ssl, https, gsm, at-command

I am trying to upload analogue values to a private server using PUT Request.

I am using Telit ME9 Module to upload data.I use AT Commands to configure the PDP and to register the network.

But while i am trying to enable the SSL it is always showing ERROR response. Dont know why??

AT#SSLEN=1,1 is the command i am trying to enable the SSL.I can only continue the further process after enable the SSL Socket.

Comment: Please, post the entire sequence of commands you sent (for example: did you activate SSL encryption on different applications too?). Please, do it after enabling verbose errors with `AT+CMEE=2`

Comment: AT
AT
OK
AT#SGACT=1,1
AT#SGACT=1,1
#SGACT: 148.68.131.136

OK
AT#SSLEN=1,1
AT#SSLEN=1,1
OK
AT#SSLD=1,443,"www.todo.com",0,0
AT#SSLD=1,443,"www.todo.com",0,0
ERROR

Comment: AT#SSLEN=1,1 seems OK now.But AT#SSLD returns 0

Comment: Again, provide `AT+CMEE=2` before the sequence e report to me the error you get.

Comment: After this i am trying to open the Server

AT#SSLD=1,443,"https://www.to4do.com/Thingworx/Things/Thg_GW_xszg_584d/Properties/sdata",0,0
ERROR

Also tried with

AT#SSLD=1,443,"www.to4do.com",0,0
ERROR

When i used IP Address in online mode

AT#SSLD=1,443,"118.155.226.139/Thingworx/Things/Thg_GW_xszg_584d/Properties/sdata",0,0
CONNECT

But AT#SSLS=1,2,0

Same in Command Mode.

I am trying by saving the CA Certificate that i recieved by clicking on the lock icon appears on the left side link when search in the browser.

Comment: AT#SSLSECDATA=1,2,1
AT#SSLSECDATA=1,2,1
#SSLSECDATA: 1,1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: Can you help me please??

Comment: AT#SSLD=1,443,"https://www.to4do.com/Thingworx/Things/Thg_GW_xszg_584d/Properties/sdata",0,0
AT#SSLD=1,443,"https://www.to4do.com/Thingworx/Things/Thg_GW_xszg_584d/Properties/sdata",0,0
+CME ERROR: Can not resolve name

Comment: AT#SSLD=1,443,"118.155.226.139/Thingworx/Things/Thg_GW_xszg_584d/Properties/sdata",0,0
AT#SSLD=1,443,"118.155.226.139/Thingworx/Things/Thg_GW_xszg_584d/Properties/sdata",0,0
+CME ERROR: SSL certs and keys wrong or not stored